# Remove relationship in a many-to-many relationship using a DataServiceCollection

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, ado.net

I have a mysql database that uses a many-to-many relationship. My schema looks like this:

[image]

I have a table "relations" that does the mapping between the two. It has 2 columns : layout_ID and graph_ID and looks like so:

[image]

What I want to do is do is delete and entry in the relationship table without deleting the object itself.

In my code, I track the 2 tables using DataServiceCollection like this:

```
var LayoutCollection = new DataServiceCollection<permalinkslayout>();
var GraphsCollection = new DataServiceCollection<permalinksgraphs>();

var Entities = new PermalinksEntities(new Uri("URL HERE"))
            {
                MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges
            };

LayoutCollection.Load(Entities.permalinkslayout.Expand("permalinksgraphs"));
GraphsCollection.Load(Entities.permalinksgraphs.Expand("permalinkslayout"));
```

Want I want to do is take a "layout" and remove the "graphs" that are associated with it (without deleting the graphs object themselves, because they can very well be associated with other "layouts")

I've tried doing

```
layout.permalinksgraphs.Clear(); (where layout is of type permalinkslayout)
Entities.SaveChanges();
```

but it doesn't remove the relationship from the database. (I don't get an error. It just doesn't update the table)

So my question is, how can I remove the relationship between a "layout" and a "graph" without deleting the "graph" object itself?

**EDIT**: here the DDL for the relationship table:

```
CREATE TABLE `permalinksrelations` (
  `layout_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `graphs_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`layout_ID`,`graphs_ID`),
  KEY `FK_layout_ID_idx` (`layout_ID`),
  KEY `FK_graphs_ID_idx` (`graphs_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_graphs_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`graphs_ID`) REFERENCES `permalinksgraphs`
  (`ID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
   CONSTRAINT `FK_layout_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`layout_ID`) REFERENCES `permalinkslayout`
  (`ID`)   ON DELETE NO ACTIONON UPDATE NO ACTION ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT  CHARSET=latin1$$
```

Comment: Is there a foreign key constraint on the relations table?

Comment: @Mike Brant Yes, there are FK constraints on layout_Id and graph_ID. Could that be a problem?

Comment: If the foreign key restricts such a delete, it would be a problem.  You should post your table DDL's.

Comment: Alright, I edited my post. I don't get constraint error though when I run the Save command. The ".Clear" updates is local context, but the relationship table on the DB remains unchanged.